# Drawing a curved line shape using assembly language

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86-16, curve, emu8086

What can I do to curve this line? Thanks.

```
MOV AH, 0CH
MOV AL, 10
MOV CX, 30
MOV DX, 50
INT 10H
```

Comment: What video mode are you in?

Answer (score 2):

If you check [the interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0104.htm) you can find that `ah=0x0C, int 0x10` is not a function that draws a line. It draws a single pixel. Therefore, there is no "line" to curve.

To draw a line you need to calculate each x and y value for a line and use `int 0x10` to draw the relevant pixels. To draw a curve, a bezier curve could be used which is a common model for drawing curves.

Learn more about bezier curves and change your code to draw a [bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#).